# Asp.net inbuilt login to hide the menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, login-control

I am making an ASP.NET MVC application using the in-built login. This page also has 2 menu items which the user can access without login.

My requirement is the user should be able to access any of the menu items until he logs in, so either I need to hide the menu items or disable the clicks on it until the user has logged in.

How can I do that?

Comment: Issue is menu bar links have few pages in ASP.net MVC and few in Asp.net... Menu bar links to few pages in MVC and few in asp.net... for MVC I could control it by [Authorize], but how do I control links for asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Razor Views then you could use something like this:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <span><a href="#">@user.ShortName</a></span>
    <text> 
    @Html.ActionLink("My Profile", "profile", "account") |
    @Html.ActionLink("Help", "index", "help") |
    @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")
    </text>
}
```

The code within the @if {...} block is what you would show if the user is logged in.

There's equivalent code for WebForms (.aspx) Views, which you could do in a number of ways.

One way would be to work from the code-behind and manipulate server controls.  So your .aspx page would have something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkMyProfile" Text="My Profile" NavigateUrl="/myprofile"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Then in your code-behind (.aspx.cs for example):

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
  lnkMyProfile.Visible = true;
} else {
  lnkMyProfile.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Issue is I have few pages in ASP.net MVC and few in Asp.net... Menu bar links to few pages in MVC and few in asp.net... for MVC I could control it by [Authorize], but how do I control links for asp.net